# Cucumber --format html fails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, report, cucumber

I recently had to re-install my Ruby environment and now when I try to execute the command:

```
cucumber features\BasicLogin.feature --out reports
```

I get the following error -

```
undefined method `new' for HTML:Module (NoMethodError)
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.11/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:183:in `block in formatters'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.11/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:178:in `map'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.11/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:178:in `formatters'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.11/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:76:in `build_tree_walker'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.11/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:46:in `run!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.11/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.11/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

I have not a clue as to what is happening, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found that the --out filename is what is problematic. If I just >> filename it works.

Comment: Try `cucumber features\BasicLogin.feature --format html --out report.html`